# SSL session resumption using tickets in k8s ingress controller replicas doesn't work

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

We have k8s-cluster with ingress-controller (nginx version: nginx/1.17.8, ingress: rke2-ingress-nginx:1.36.301) - 4 replicas (one per worker)

To improve performance and be able to reuse the session between many replicas, I try to activate the ssl_session_cache & tickets.

ingress-configmap have following data-Block:

```
  ssl-session-cache-size: 100m

  ssl-session-tickets: "true"

  ssl-session-timeout: 1440m

  ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.2"

  ssl-session-ticket-key: "RESULT OF openssl rand 80 | openssl enc -A -base64"
```

When i decrease replica count to 1, i get correct handshake and i can reuse the ticket in further requests without handshake.

When i increase the replicas count to > 1, and send the session ticket in second (third, fourth...) request (round-robin), i'm getting each time a new ticket from the server incl. full handshake. So session resumption doesn't work.

Configmap auto-update is working, each replica have the same nginx.conf and all the replicas have the same /etc/nginx/tickets.key

Ingress-controller-pod logs have no issues while updating the configmap:

> I0929 13:56:50.165135       8 controller.go:137] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.

> I0929 13:56:50.267572       8 controller.go:153] Backend successfully reloaded.

Restarting all ingress-pods after updating the configmap also doesn't help.

**Result of the configmap in nginx.conf**:

```
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

        ssl_early_data off;

        # turn on session caching to drastically improve performance

        ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:100m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

        # allow configuring ssl session tickets
        ssl_session_tickets on;

        ssl_session_ticket_key /etc/nginx/tickets.key;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which `nginx ingress` exactly is used? Also I see it's quite outdated at the first glance.

Comment: Hi @moonkotte rke2-ingress-nginx:1.36.301